# Unhandled promise rejection in express route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting this error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

from this portion of my express route route:

```
router.post('/', jsonParser, (req, res) => {

    // checking that given id is valid

    let { id } = req.body; 

    User.findById({ id })
        .count()
        .then(count => {
            if (count < 1) {
                return Promise.reject({
                    code: 422, 
                    reason: 'Validation Error', 
                    message: 'Family must be created by a user', 
                    location: 'id'
                })
            } 
            return resolve(); 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(err.code).json({code: err.code, message: err.message, reason: err.reason, location: err.location })
        }); 

    ...
```

I'm not stellar at promises. Can someone see what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: You are already inside a promise callback. So you should use throw rather than reject.

Answer (score 0):

`resolve` is `undefined`, you could use `return count` instead, to pass data to the next promise:

```
User.findById({ id })
        .count()
        .then(count => {
            if (count < 1) {
                throw new Error('Family must be created by a user')
            } 
            // success
            return count;
        })
        .then( res => { // res will be count if the promise not rejected
             res.json({ success: true, count: res })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(422).json({
                code: 422, 
                reason: 'Validation Error', 
                message: 'Family must be created by a user', 
                location: 'id'
            })
        });
```

Comment: Yeah I tried the Promise.resolve() bit and still isn't working. Very strange.

Comment: Try to use throw as described by @notionquest comment, I updated my answer

Comment: I actually have much more in the route down the line, so I don't want to use res yet. This is just a check before the real work in the route starts

Comment: This is just a check to make sure a real user is creating a fmaily. After I check that the id is valid, I create a family. So if I use res as you have it above, I will be exited out of the entire route, which isn't what I want to do quite

Comment: I see, you could use return statement to send data to the next promise chain

Answer (score 0):

```
.catch(err => { return res.status(err.code).json({code: err.code, message: err.message, reason: err.reason, location: err.location }) });
```

Here lies the issue. when a response is sent you can not send another response. So when you do

> res.status(), express sends the response with status code. and .json() will give exception.

try setting status like this. 
res.statusCode = code;  and then
res.json()